# db connection error node-mysql docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-mysql

I've 2 container one of webapp(node) second of db(mysql) are in same docker network. But when running both container via docker compose, my app is not able to connect to database. Getting below error, when i check the webapp container logs.

Error connecting: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.28.0.2:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)

NOTE: i am able to access the mysql container from docker host and also able to ping the mysql container from webapp(node ) container.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since both containers are running in the same network, try changing the `HOST` from `172.28.0.2:3306` to `127.0.0.1:3306`.

Comment: Same errror is there:

   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
Error connecting: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)

Comment: Have you tried it without docker? Is it working fine? What is the configuration?

Comment: Yes it works fine without docker, and this is my compose file:

version: "3.2"
services:
  mysql_db:
    build: ./db
    ports:
      - "6603:3306"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST= mysql_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_USER=****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=****
    container_name: db_cont
    networks:
     - my_net
    restart: always
  nodejs_app:
    build: ./web
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    container_name: app_cont1
    networks:
     - my_net

    ports:
      - "3035:3035"

networks:
  my_net: